# Sitecore Rich Text Field Max Length

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.5

Is there a way to set a Max Length for characters entered into a Rich Text field in Sitecore 7.5? For example, I have an MVC View Rendering that displays quotes but the front end elements are designed so that the characters need to be within the parameters otherwise it looks awful. Personally I would rather have the CSS handle this but I'm not a front end dev and the client wants what the client wants :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a apply a Validation Rule to the field on your template. When you select the Field under your template there is a Validation Rules section where you can select which rules to apply, there are 4 fields for different types of validation. Create a copy of the `/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Rules/Sample/Max Length 40` and set the MaxLength in parameters field.

[Using Sitecore Field Validators](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/05/09/using-sitecore-field-validators/)

These rules however do not stop the user from saving the Item, they only provide warnings either next to the field, to the Validator bar or require the user to manually click Review > Validation. Another option is to set a RegEx in Validation and the error message in ValidationText field.

[Sitecore Custom Field and Item Validation Basics](http://www.awareweb.com/awareblog/11-11-14-sitecore-custom-field)

In both cases, since you are using a Rich Text Field it will be possible for the user to style the text. Be aware that the default MaxLength validator will probably include the HTML markup text in it's length count, whereas you are probably only interested in the actual text length. If this is an issue then you can create your own custom validator, strip out any markup and then check the length.